# Flutter - how do I make a widget draw only after shared preferences have been read?

Tags: flutter, future

I'm trying to get to grips with Flutter by creating an app which draws a random path (it will get more advanced before it's finished!).  The user can change the number of tiles in the path, and this value gets saved in Shared Preferences. If they don't change the number of tiles, it's set to its default value of 15.5.

The problem I have is that it's trying to draw the path before it's finished reading the Shared Preferences, and crashing out because the number of tiles isn't set.  I could set the default value, but then it would draw that first, and then redraw with a different number of tiles, which I don't want - I want it to draw the user-set number of tiles first, and only use the default value if the user hasn't set the number.

I think I need to use a `FutureBuilder`, but I can't find a lot online that I can get my head around.  Here's what I have so far (this is main.dart):

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "Path Maker",
    home: PathMaker(),
  ));
}

class PathMaker extends StatefulWidget {

  int numTiles;

  PathMaker({
        Key key,
        this.numTiles
    }): super(key: key);

  @override
  _PathMakerState createState() => new _PathMakerState();

}

class _PathMakerState extends State<PathMaker> {

  _PathMakerState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getPreferences();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void getPreferences() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      // Get timing variables
      Set<String> keys = prefs.getKeys();
      if(keys.contains('numTiles')) {
        numTiles = prefs.getInt('numTiles');
      }else {
        numTiles = 15.5;
      }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Path Maker',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: new Path(widget.numTiles),
    );
  }

}
```

(path.dart is another file which defines the `Path` class - I don't think it's relevant, but can post it if needed). So, basically, I want it to call build only after `getPreferences` has completed. How do I handle this? Am I taking the wrong approach completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track using a `FutureBuilder`.

It has two parameters, the `future` which expected some `Future` which is a delayed computation or a potential value. In your case this is the `Future<SharedPreferences>` returned from `SharedPreferences.getInstance()`.

Then then `FutureBuilder` expects a `builder`. The builder will be called with the context and an `AsyncSnapshot` corresponding to the type of your future. The `AsyncSnapshot` is the representation of the most recent interaction with an asynchronous computation - in your case the retrieval of the shared preferences instance. The `AsyncSnapshot.connectionState` allows us to decide what widget to render based on the state of the `Future`. The [`FutureBuilder` example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) goes into detail about the different states, for now we will just look at `ConnectionState.done`.

In the `done` state the snapshot contains either an error - which we're not going to deal with here - or `data`, the return value of your asynchronous function call.

Taking your example we can create a `FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>`. The generic type indicates the type that the future will return. We assign the future from the shared preferences `getInstance` method to the future parameter and a builder closure that expects the context and the async snapshot.

With this your code could look like this:

```
class _PathMakerState extends State<PathMaker> {
  _PathMakerState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setTiles(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    // Get timing variables
    Set<String> keys = prefs.getKeys();
    if(keys.contains('numTiles')) {
      widget.numTiles = prefs.getDouble('numTiles');
    }else {
      widget.numTiles = 15.5;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Path Maker',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>(
        future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              // get the tile number from the shared preference instance
              // stored in snapshot.data
              setTiles(snapshot.data);
              return Path(widget.numTiles);
            default:
              return Text("Loading...");
          }
        }
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's very helpful, and makes sense at last!  Best explanation I've come across, to be honest.